Claude Somnet 3.5 and Dates
I'm pretty stumped by this one and wonder if y'all have any ideas.
I'm building an application using Claude 3 Sonnet in Amazon Bedrock.
I need it to work with relative dates, and it was constantly returning dates one day off. So I ran the test below - 16 Nov 2024 is a Saturday, but it says it's a Friday.
Any ideas on what could be happening?
(For what's worth, I'm in New Zealand - technically it's still Friday in other parts of the world, but I'm using Bedrock in ap-southeast-2 which is in Australia, so they're also in the same date as me - I'm grasping at straws with ideas here)
Prompt:
Today is 16 Nov 2024
Which day is next Tuesday

Answer:
Got it, today is November 16th, 2024.

Since today is a Friday, and there are 7 days in a week:

Friday (Nov 16)
Saturday (Nov 17)
Sunday (Nov 18) 
Monday (Nov 19)
Tuesday (Nov 20) <-- This is next Tuesday

Therefore, next Tuesday is November 20th, 2024.```


BTW, I've asked for access to v3.5 as I can see that it works fine in claude.ai, but just interested to learn what could be causing this in v3.
